# Microsoft Access remove part of string

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm building a query using a html file converted to a text file as the source.

I need to remove the first part of some fields, and the last part of others, for example:

```
class="nohover">Product
Price</a></h3>
```

The html code can vary in length. Any ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I've not made that too clear. I need to remove all traces of HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions Left, Right, Mid, InStr and, in some cases, Replace.

```
s = "class=""nohover"">Product Price</a></h3>"
s = Mid(a, InStr(a, ">") + 1)
s = Left(a, InStr(a, "<") - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know the functions, just not the correct syntax, especially when the string is variable length.

Comment: @Karmik You had not yet added the clarifying comment when I posted. I have added some notes.

Comment: Thanks Remou, let me play with those and come back to you.